# Generate uml class diagram from existing angularjs code

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, uml

I am looking for a tool like [Angularjs explorer viewer](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Angular-Explorer-View) that can generate mvc diagram including all the controller/services and the dependencies between them from existing angularjs code. This one is a plugin in eclipse. And I failed to installed it when I tried to followed the instruction [Getting started](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started).
the error said :

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: tern feature
>   0.3.0.201406242125 (tern-feature.feature.group 0.3.0.201406242125)   Missing requirement: Tern - Server - Nodejs 0.3.0.201406242125
>   (tern.server.nodejs 0.3.0.201406242125) requires 'package
>   org.apache.http 0.0.0' but it could not be found   Missing
>   requirement: Tern - Server - Nodejs 0.4.0.201407211814
>   (tern.server.nodejs 0.4.0.201407211814) requires 'package
>   org.apache.http 0.0.0' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: tern feature 0.3.0.201406242125 (tern-feature.feature.group 0.3.0.201406242125)
>       To: tern.eclipse.ide.core [0.3.0.201406242125]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Tern - Eclipse - Core IDE 0.3.0.201406242125 (tern.eclipse.ide.core 0.3.0.201406242125)
>       To: bundle tern.server.nodejs 0.2.0

Is there any?

Thanks

Comment: -1 for not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question §4 and no research effort shown. You can find similar questions with helpful answers using Google search for phrase "```site:stackoverflow.com javascript uml reverse engineering```". BTW: if you find your useful answer you can post it here, I'd also like to know, but right now it seems to me that such tool will not exist as JavaScript does not have agreed-on OOP class model that parsers and tools might use (until ES6 comes out)

Answer (score 2):

This question is about installation of [AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse). It seems that your Eclipse has not the plugin *org.apache.http*.

I suggest you to use Eclipse Luna (4.4) and the distribution **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS Eclipse is based on tern.java which is based on tern.js a JS inference engine. So you could use just tern.js with Grunt task for instance to call angular tern plugin which will parse your JS files and returns a JSON with Module, Contrroller, etc. Never done that but I think it's possible.